# Angular Custom Element not binding object to input

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element

I am trying to use a custom element created in Angular 8.2

Here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Element just</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script defer src="my-custom-elements-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-custom-element context='{"id":"1", "country":"US", "language":"EN"}'></my-custom-element>
 </body>
</html>
```

Although context is expected to be type of IContext, it is being bind as a string. How can I make it bind to object and not the object's stringified version instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you write `context=` angular expects a string.

In your case use `[context]=` so angular treated this as an object.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Element just</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script defer src="my-custom-elements-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-custom-element [context]='{"id":"1", "country":"US", "language":"EN"}'></my-custom-element>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `context=` expects a literal string (not a bool, number nor string variable). Anything other than a string is stringified, so if you pass `true`, it becomes the string `" true"`, if you pass `45` it becomes the string `"45"` and if you pass the variable `myVariable` it becomes the string `"myVariable"`

Comment: Thanks Norbert . I wanted use the angular custom element in a plain HTML application with javascript . And the below code helped me to accomplish the same .

var temp = JSON.parse('{"id":"1", "country":"US", "language":"EN"}')